# Cordova Android project creation

Tags: android-layout, cordova

I have followed the steps:

1. npm install -g cordova
2. cordova create  workshop com.yourname.workshop Workshop
3. cd workshop
4. cordova platforms add android

I am getting this error after add android:

```
    C:\Users\SCube\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\node_modules\
                        throw e;
                              ^ Error: ERROR : executing command 'ant', make sure you have ant inst ed to your path.
        at C:\Users\SCube\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\lib\ch 7:27
        at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:641:7)
        at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
        at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
        at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:5) Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 8
        at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\SCube\AppData\Roaming\npm\no rdova\src\superspawn.js:112:23)
        at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
        at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
        at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:5)
```

Any ideas how to resolve this error? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, you may need to include %ANT_HOME%\bin to your PATH as well. To check to see if this is required, run a command prompt and type ant. If the program can not be found add %ANT_HOME%\bin to the PATH. You may need to specify the full path instead of using the %ANT_HOME% environment variable.

Donlowad ant :  https://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html

This is probably because its not able to find the ant executable in your Path.
I'm assuming you've installed Apache Ant. (http://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi)

Assuming you're on Windows, you need to set your ANT_HOME and add the ant bin to your PATH environment variable

So My Computer > Proprties > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables

Add a new Variable called ANT_HOME
Set the value to be the base directory of your apache ant installation, eg :

[image: ANT_HOME Environment Variable]

Then add the location of the ANT Bin directory to your PATH Variable, which will already exist.
eg : Add ;C:\apache-ant-1.8.4\bin to the end of the PATH System Variable

[image: Set the ANT bin directory to your PATH Environment Variable]

After you've done this, you will need to launch a new command window and then ant can be used.

Even now, ant will work if you explicitly navigate to the Ant Installation's bin directory and type ANT.

Follow this Link for Ans :  http://www.systenics.com/blog/setup-phonegap-34-on-windows-8-64-bit-to-create-android-applications/